# Moving a Background Image from the top with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

Basically..

I want to move the the background image that is for main div 200px from the top and then repeat on the y axis. So I don't want it to start for 200px; Can I do that through CSS? The only way I can think of is below, but it is not working.

I know I am doing somethign wrong, but what is it?

**Here is the DIV:**

```
<div class="main">
<p> Content Content </p>
</div>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```css
.main { 
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/addedimages/main-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y; 
    background-position: 200px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [`background-origin` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-origin) (but note [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-origin)).

Comment: Ahhh! I need it to support more than one browser, well all browsers. can't be using something that will work in places...

Answer (score 1):

i would try to move the div down with positiv margin and the p up to a negative margin. maybe you need some `postion: relative`, or so.

Comment: I have content contained inside of thee div. (up top is just a basic example of what I want).. I have a lot of code elsewhere and need to just get to the bottom of this; no point you lot seeing everything otherwise it will be cluttered information.

Comment: take a div instead of the p and put your whole content in it.
then use the same idea ....

Answer (score -1):

background-position only accepts to parameters: offset left, offset top...

background: url('image.url') 0px 200px repeat-y;

so you're not completely wrong with your solution, if you wanted to cut 200px of the first picture, (and than repeat the whole picture).

Comment: `background-position` sets the offset, not the starting position. That will put the top of the image 200px from the top, but it will also put the bottom of the previous one in the same spot

Comment: ok :) actually what I meant, or trying to say with "cut off, ..." but I didn't find the right words.